# creating an array on the heap, typedef pointer to it, Segmentation fault: 11 when accessing it

Tags: c

What's wrong with this?

```
typedef unsigned char * test;

void init_test(test t);
void insert(test t);

int main() {
    test t;

    init_test(t);
    insert(t);

    printf("%d\n", t[3]);

    return 0;
}

void init_test(test t) {
    t = (test)malloc(100 * sizeof(test));
}

void insert(test t) {
    t[0] = 200;
    t[1] = 201;
    t[2] = 202;
    t[3] = 203;
    t[4] = 204;
}
```

It outputs 203 but then Segmentation fault: 11.

It's a stripped down version of the proper version. On the proper version I don't even get the value output before the seg fault.

Comment: `free` your allocated memory!!!

Comment: Oh, is that all it is? I didn't realise not doing that would cause that kind of a problem. I'll have a look at that. Thanks.

Comment: from the quick glance i took, idk if that is the only issue but it certainly needs to be done

Comment: Note: if you are going to use a pointer typedef, try and make its name clear, eg 'pMyDataStruct'.

Comment: Note: **Never ever** `typedef` an object pointer. It will mess up your code eventually. It also makes writing const-correct code either impossible or floods the namespace.

Comment: @Olaf well, sometimes the alternative is having the code flooded with stars:(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: As you should add some marker to the name anyway to make clear it is a pointer, what's the difference adding a single `*`? If you refer to 3-star programmers: that does not justify `typedef`ing pointers - either way, such an interface is broken by design. From my over 20 years of C experience alone, I can assure you there is always a much better way; I never needed 3-star pointers in fact - with or without typedef. Not to forget the qualifier-correctness explodes with multiple indirection.

Answer (score 1):

This can't work:

```
void init_test(test t) {
    t = (test)malloc(100 * sizeof(test));
}
```

It does not assign `t` to the **caller** `init_test(t)`, it just throws the pointer away since the argument `t` goes out of scope and its lifetime ends at the end of the function. You would have to save the malloc result and pass it to the caller, e.g. with

```
init_test(&t);
```

along with this

```
void init_test(test *t) {
   *t = malloc(100 * sizeof **t);
}
```

And **don't cast malloc** (search this site why).

Comment: Right, I get the local issue, thought (wishfully/blindly) the pointer in the typedef would avoid that. I've tried your suggestion. Bus error: 10. I would prefer to use the pointer method rather than the function returning a value. I can't get the code to have returns in this comment, will post code below.

Answer (score 1):

In C, all function parameters are pass by value.  So your `init_test` function is updating a local value which is not reflected in the calling function.  As a result, `t` in `main` is still uninitialized after this call.  You then pass this uninitialized pointer to `insert` which tries to dereference that pointer.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests as a crash.

Instead of taking a parameter, have `init_test` return the allocated pointer and assign the return value to `t`.

So define your function like this:

```
test init_test() {
    test t = malloc(100 * sizeof(*t));  // not sizeof(test)
    if (t==NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
t = init_test();
```

Also, it's not a good idea to hide a pointer inside of a `typedef`.  It obscures the fact that you're using a pointer and can be confusing to readers of your code (including yourself).

Comment: OK, thanks. I haven't tried that but can see it'll work. I want to use pointers though if pos, so I'm sticking and hoping to get Jens way working, but it's not at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(*test)`  is a syntax error, I guess you mean `sizeof *t`

Comment: @M.M Good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. You were working with local variable('t').

```
typedef unsigned char * test;

test init_test(test t);
test insert(test t);



int main() {

    test t;
    t = init_test(t);
    t = insert(t);

    printf("%d\n", t[3]);

    free(t);
    return 0;
}

test init_test(test t) {
    t = (test)malloc(100 * sizeof(test));
     return t;
}

test insert(test t) {
    t[0] = 200;
    t[1] = 201;
    t[2] = 202;
    t[3] = 203;
    t[4] = 204;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: The function parameter is redundant and should be removed to avoid confusion (and UB).